# Display admin/custom screen after solution import?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-365

I'm using dynamic 365, and my requirement is to display a custom screen after importing a certain solution to an organization? Is it possible? can someone suggest a solution to this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an immediate popup after solution installation then I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Oh, so there's no way that it can be achieved. How about instead of a custom screen after solution import, a button will be added/displayed on Settings > Solutions page, like the behaviour when installing an ADXStudion in CRM?

Comment: Sure, that would work - include command bar customisations in your solution, you could also add a configuration page to your solution. https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/212695

Comment: Hi @James, can you provide me url or any links on how to add command bar on my solution page?

Comment: Google it, look for command bar, or ribbon customisations. Also check out Ribbon Workbench.